# Optional child selector, with CSS/Stylus/LESS: .aa > .bb? > .cc

Tags: css, css-selectors, less, stylus

Consider this HTML with CSS classes *aa*, *bb* and *cc*:

```
<div class='aa'>
<div class='bb'>
<div class='cc'>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I can select the `class=cc` tag like so: `.aa > .bb > .cc`. However, in my case, sometimes the `.bb` tag is absent, that is, the HTML looks like so:

```
<div class='aa'>
<div class='cc'>
</div>
</div>
```

Thererfore, to select all `.cc` close to an `.aa`, I'd need to specify two CSS paths:

```
.aa > .bb > .cc,
.aa > .cc { .... }
```

This works, but, is there no shorter way? Something similar to this:

```
.aa > (.bb >)? .cc { ... }   /* ? means "optional" */
```

with CSS or something like Stylus or LESS?

Motivation: In the real world, "aa" and "bb" and "cc" are somewhat longer names, and there's more stuff before and after the "aa" and "cc", and it'd be nice to not need to duplicate that stuff.

Please note: In my case, this won't work: `.aa .cc` because that'd match too many `.cc`s elsewhere on the page. The `.cc`s need to be either immediately below the `.aa`, or below `.aa > .bb`.

Comment: If `.aa .cc` is too general because you don't want to match `.cc` elements that are more distant descendants of `.aa` elements, then I think the `.aa > .bb > .cc, .aa > .cc` selector you already mentioned is best.

Comment: In standard CSS there is no other way.

Comment: Are `.bb` and `.cc` the only two possible children of `.aa`?

Comment: @BoltClock No, `.aa` has other children too. (What did you have in mind, if the  answer had been yes?)

Comment: I would have suggested `.aa > .cc, .aa > * > .cc`. Doesn't do much, but it would allow you to skip typing `.bb`...

Comment: Any updates? I've got the same question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Stylus and Sass you could do this ([live example for Sass](http://codepen.io/kizu/pen/kEhfp)):

```
.aa
  > .bb, &
    > .cc
      width: 10px
```

I couldn't find a way to do so in a one-liner for Sass, but for Less/Stylus/Scss you could do also this (live examples [for Scss](http://codepen.io/kizu/pen/zIkpC), [for Less](http://codepen.io/kizu/pen/BuCem)) :

```
.aa { > .bb, & { > .cc {
  width: 10px
}}}
```

This is not that pretty also, but still better than nothing :)

Comment: I almost thought it was not possible! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't `.aa > .cc, .aa > .bb > .cc {}` work? Or did I misunderstand your question?
This selects only the `.cc` that are direct `.aa` children and the `.cc` that are `.bb` children (children of `.aa`) as well.

Comment: Yes it'd work, but I was wondering if there's a shorter alternative.

Answer (score 1):

if you want use your option, by the way is very interesting, you can use a form most correct:

```
>.aa (>.bb)? >.cc { ... }
```

but the form correct would:

```
.aa .cc { ... }
```

into stylus:

```
.aa   
  .cc
```

thats all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I don't really understand it. I don't realize what you mean with *"you can use a form most correct"* Are you saying that `.aa (>.bb)? >.cc { ... }` is valid CSS? (I don't think it is)

Answer (score 0):

I used :has() solution, for giving selector reinforcement when available

```
//adds .specific-ancestor-class as more specific selector, when available as ancestor, otherwise select inner with less specificity
*:has(.specific-ancestor-class, *){
    .inner {
        //style...
    }
}
```